# props passed to Page from getServerSideProps is always undefined

Tags: next.js

I'm using nextjs 9.3.5 and even the simplest example of getServerSideProps is always failing:

```js
function Page({ data })
{
    //Prints undefined
    console.log(data);

    return <div>Data in props: {data}</div>
}

export async function getServerSideProps()
{
    var data = "Hello";

    //Prints "Hello"
    console.log(data);

    return { props: { data } };
}

export default Page
```

This is basically a cut and paste from the very simple example on the nextjs website. getInitialProps works fine.

Comment: Might help to post how Page is being called, since data is not being passed properly to Page.  edit: nevermind, looks like it's all built-in hooks

Comment: I've copied your example to Next.js 9.3.5 and it works as expected. It's not reproducible

Comment: I have the same problem. I can see getServerSideProps() gets called, but I do not see the Page.json in the network as I have seen on other people's example.

Comment: have you added _app.js file ?

Answer (score 12):

In case you added `_app.js` file into your project according [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) you need add `Component` and `pageProps` inside, here is a minimal implementation of `_app.js` file.

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
   return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Still same error as it is already in my _app.tsx

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I realised that I was using `getServerSideProps` in the component that is not the actual page, rather it was my card component that I was displaying on the page.

Answer (score 2):

It only console.log undefined when you trying to pass the session from the serversideprops to the componet

```
const profile = ({session}) => {

console.log(session) //this print undefined 


  return (<div>Profile</div>)
}
export default profile

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const session = await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions)

if (!session) {
  return {
    redirect: {
      destination: '/',
      permanent: false,
    },
  }
}

return {
    props: {session}, // will be passed to the page component as props
}
```

}

this console.log print undefined because session contain important data that should not be pass or access in the client

to fix this you can define a new variable and assign the session to it. it will automatically put the data that it is ok  to pass to client

```
const profile = ({clientData}) => {

console.log(clientData) //this print a specific part of the session that it is ok to print on the client 


    return (<div>Profile</div>)
}
export default profile

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

    const session = await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions)

    if (!session) {
        return {
        redirect: {
            destination: '/',
            permanent: false,
        },
        }
    }

    const clientData = session
    
    return {
        props: {clientData }, // will be passed to the page component as props
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check you component, it not under src/pages or whatever rootDir/pages

Answer (score -3):

This should be in the structure of your json that you are returning as a prop.

Try this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const data = {title:"Hello Sir"};
  return { props:  data }
}
```